# PermissionDoesNotExist (there is no permission with id 1) In spatie Permission Package Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-permission

i am using the spatie permission package.I want to assign a permission to a role.Below Is my method in controller:

```
 public function testing_role_permission()
{
  $role = Role::findById(2);
  $permission = Permission::findById(1);
  $role->givePermissionTo($permission);

}
```

It is showing me exception **PermissionDoesNotExist
There is no [permission] with id `1`**.

Before it the same method was working and permission was assigned to the role.But i create some new permissions in PermissionTableSeeder.After doing this it's not working.I searched a lot trying to clear cache but nothing happen to this Exception.

**PermissionTableSeeder.php**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Role;
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Permission;
class PermissionTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
/**
 * Run the database seeds.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function run()
{

    app()[\Spatie\Permission\PermissionRegistrar::class]- 
    >forgetCachedPermissions();
    //role permissions
     Permission::create(['name' => 'create_role']);
     Permission::create(['name' => 'read_role']);
     Permission::create(['name' => 'update_role']);
     Permission::create(['name' => 'delete_role']);
     Permission::create(['name' => 'disable_role']);
     Permission::create(['name' => 'isolation_role']);
    }
    }
```

**How to Solve this Error?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check whether theres a permission with id 1 in database.

Answer (score 1):

In your permission table give check your guard_name. If it is empty or something mismatch then maybe you are getting that error.